# Decoding Google Speech API response in python

Tags: python, json, google-api

I'm trying to use the Google Speech API in Python. I load a .flac file like this:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"
audio = open('temp_voice.flac','rb').read()
headers = {'Content-Type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=44100', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data=audio, headers=headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
system("rm temp_voice.wav; rm temp_voice.flac")
print resp.read()
```

Output:

{"status":0,"id":"","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"Today is Wednesday","confidence":0.75135982}]}

Can someone please teach me how I can extract and save the text **"Today is Wednesday"** as a variable and print it?

Comment: How about using [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `json.loads` to convert the JSON data to a dict, like this

```
data = '{"status":0,"id":"","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"Today is Wednesday","confidence":0.75135982}]}'
import json
data = json.loads(data)
print data["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me though. I get the following:                             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: I just added the code to my original post. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Stralo But this doesnt have the part where `json` is used

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to do that and that's why I'm asking for help. I added your suggestion at the end of the code and got the ValueError I mentioned earlier. I did data=resp.read()  text=json.loads(data)   print text["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"]

Answer (score 0):

If the response is coming as a string then you can just eval it to a dictionary, (for safety it is preferable to use `literal_eval` from the `ast` library instead):

```
>>> d=eval('{"status":0,"id":"","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"Today is Wednesday","confidence":0.75135982}]}')
>>> d
{'status': 0, 'hypotheses': [{'confidence': 0.75135982, 'utterance': 'Today is Wednesday'}], 'id': ''}  

>>> h=d.get('hypotheses')                                                                            
>>> h                                                                                                 
[{'confidence': 0.75135982, 'utterance': 'Today is Wednesday'}]                                       
>>> for i in h:                                                                                       
...    print i.get('utterance')
... 
Today is Wednesday
```

Of course if it is already a dictionary then you do not need to do the evaluate, try using `print type(response)` where `response` is the result you are getting.

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is the safe way to do this. `eval` should never be used for this.

Comment: I tried text=eval(str(response.read()))   print text  and got File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Sounds like either the buffer filled up or the connection was lost before the end of the full string _or_ you got some malformed string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with retrieve output is bit more complicate that looks. At first  resp is type of instance, however if you copy the output manually is dictionary->list->dictionary. If you assign the resp.read() to new variable you will get type string with length 0. It happens, because the all output vanish into air once is used (print). Therefore the json decoding has to be done as soon the respond from google api is granted. As follow:

resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

text = json.loads(resp.read())["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"]

Works like a charm in my case ;)